# Hide form upon submission

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to set the form's display to none when the submit button is pressed. 
But this code is not working.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("submit");
  x.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<form class="submit" method="post">
  <input id="ceg" type="text" name="ceg" placeholder="Cég neve"><br>
  <input id="ceg" type="text" name="kontakt" placeholder="Kapcsolattartó neve"><br>
  <input id="ceg" type="email" name="" placeholder="Kapcsolattartó email címe"><br>
  <input id="ceg" type="text" name="" placeholder="Munkakör leírása (20 szó)"><br>
  <h1>Témakör</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="menu" value="1">1</input><br>
  <input type="radio" name="menu" value="2">2</input><br>
  <input type="radio" name="menu" value="3">3</input><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onload="myFunction">
</form>
```

Comment: Placing the tags in the title is not necessary. If the title is not long enough without them, the problem has not been accurately described.

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique and `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. Finally there is no `</input>` tag. Inputs self-close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need javascript to solve your problem. Just put the submit class style with *display: none;* (I recommend change the name of that class, is not intuitive) and put in the form's class attribute the follow checking:

```
class="<?= (!empty($_POST)) ? 'submit' : ''; ?>"
```

The javascript's solution is only needed when you have actions that must rely without page submitions. When you submit, you lost the actual condition of the page and your scripting changes is lost.

PS: Not relative to your question, but review your html, ids must be unique and you have other stuff that can improve a bit.